# How to update state array fetched from API in React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, use-effect

I'm fetching data from Studio Ghibli API and I am able to successfully fetch it, set the state array of objects and render it in my presentational component. However, I'm trying to create a function which will add new property "keyword" to every object in my state array. The problem is that when i try to copy the state array to manipulate it in my createKeywords function, the returned copy is empty and I'm unable to manipulate it after it being set.

This is the relevant code:

```
  const baseUrl = 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/'
  const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false)
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(baseUrl + 'films')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setMovies(res)
        createKeywords()
      })
      .catch(err => setErrors(true));
  }, [])

  const createKeywords = () => {
    const moviesWithKeywords = [...movies]
    moviesWithKeywords.forEach(function(movie){
      movie.keyword = 'castle'
    }); 
    setMovies(moviesWithKeywords)
}
```

If i don't call the createKeywords function everything works fine but obviously copying and setting new movies state creates problem. I tried adding [movies] instead of empty array in useEffect and that works but then useEffect runs indefinitely. Thank you in advance, React isn't my strong suit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution seems might not be very obvious. There are cases where setMovies (in general setting the state) is an async operation, which means that even if you setMovies the movies variable is not being updated quite fast and therefore you are already executing the createKeawords function. This means that within the keywords function the movies variable didn't have the chance to update fast enough. I would recommend to pass the `res` as a parameter in the createKeywords and use this variable to copy the array to the `moviesWithKeywords`.

Have a look here under the section [State Updates May Be Asynchronous](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/get-pro-with-react-setstate-in-10-minutes-d38251d1c781/)

So do something like that:

```
  const baseUrl = 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/'
  const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false)
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(baseUrl + 'films')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setMovies(res)
        createKeywords(res)
      })
      .catch(err => setErrors(true));
  }, [])

  const createKeywords = (movies) => {
    const moviesWithKeywords = [...movies]
    moviesWithKeywords.forEach(function(movie){
      movie.keyword = 'castle'
    }); 
    setMovies(moviesWithKeywords)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me, I now use res to set the movies state inside createKeywords instead of setting it inside useEffect.

Comment: It worth to have a read in the link I've posted. Can you accept the answer as well?